# How to configure JQuery Validate and InputMask-robinherbots to work together

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, input-mask

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/inputmask.js"></script>
   <script src="js/inputmask.numeric.extensions.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

/head>
<body>
    <form class="myform">
        <h2>Enter sum</h2>
        <div>
            <input  class="numberInputUs" name="numberUs" type="text" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
      </form>
    <hr />
 </body>
</html>
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.myform').validate({
        rules: {

            numberUs: {
                required: true,
                range: [2, 100000000]
            },

        },
    });

    validateAfterLossFocus();

    setAliasForCurrency();
    $("input").val(''); 
   setMaskInput();/

});


function validateAfterLossFocus() {

    $('input').on('blur', function () {
        $(this).submit(); 
    })


}

function setAliasForCurrency(){

    Inputmask.extendAliases({
        us: {
            prefix: "$",
            groupSeparator: ".",
            alias: "numeric",
            placeholder: "0",
            autoGroup: !0,
            digits: 2,
            digitsOptional: !1,
            clearMaskOnLostFocus: !1,
            allowMinus: 'false'
        }
    });
}


function setMaskInput() {

    //$('.numberInputUs').inputmask("currency");  
    //$('.numberInputUs').inputmask({ alias: "currency", prefix: '' }); 

    $('.numberInputUs').inputmask({ alias: "us" }); 

}
```

When using such parameters in InputMask, as:
-prefix, groupseparator, digits, then validation works incorrectly.
 How to ensure that both formatting is preserved, and to be validated accurately.

I think that ' placeholders ' and ' separators ', the validator is being recognized as symbols and it is taking them into account...

**UPDATE 2**

I wrote the code like this.

```
 Inputmask.extendAliases({
        byn: {
            min: 2,
            max: 200000,
            prefix: "$",
            groupSeparator: ".",
            alias: "numeric",
            placeholder: "0",
            autoGroup: !0,
            digits: 2,
            digitsOptional: !1,
            clearMaskOnLostFocus: !1,
            allowMinus: 'false',

        }
    });
```

But the user is confused that you can enter more than this number. Also, how else to add an alert that it incorrectly enters a number

Comment: No idea what *"validation works incorrectly"* is supposed to mean.  If your input is supposed to be in a certain format, then you need to write a custom rule to validate it using that format.

Comment: I also don't understand the purpose of masking while using validation.  Seems pointless when proper validation would force the user to enter the correct format.

Comment: How can I limit the input of the amount in the Range between 2 to 200000, while retaining the input formatting?
 Please, could you show me an example

Comment: As I stated, you will need to write a custom rule that enforces your desired formatting.  Use the search function on the jQuery Validate tag using keywords "addMethod".